# What is the opposite of debt?

Tags: debt, definition

In trade, the opposite of *trade deficit* is *trade surplus*. In other words, the negative deficit is called surplus.

And then, what is the term for negative debt?

Say for example Bank A owes 5 million dollars to Bank B.

And then Bank A has a debt of 5 million dollars.
And bank B has a negative debt of 5 million dollars.

I have the same question about negative liabilities, I'm not sure if I have to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: A common contrast is between  *liability* and *asset*

Comment: You mean if Eric owes 10 USD to me then he has a debt (or liability) of 10 USD and I have an asset of 10 USD?

Comment: Yes - that is what I was suggesting